# How to append content to an existing log file without overwriting using windows command line?

Tags: file, logging, cmd, append, nant

I have a batch file where I would like to append to the same log file, without overwriting, from two or more build files. I intend to write something like below:

```
SET logdir=C:\Logs\BuildLogFile.txt
NAnt -buildfile:ServiceProxies.build > %logdir% 

SET logdir=C:\Logs\BuildLogFile.txt
NAnt -buildfile:SecurityService.build > %logdir%
```

But the txt file gets overwritten. Is there any way by which I can append to the same .txt file because I want to use a single Log file for the entire project?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `>>` to append, instead of `>`.